# How to distinguish different action that tragger worksheet change event

Tags: excel, vba, validation, msgbox

I has Validation on cells, when input break the validation a message box will pop up.

To avoid the copy paste data break validation, I use macro to validate the pase data.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Dim ValidCells As Range
    Dim Fail As Boolean
    
    Let Fail = False
    Set KeyCells = Range("A2:D2000")
    Set ValidCells = Application.Intersect(Target, KeyCells)

    If Not ValidCells Is Nothing Then
        For Each Cell In ValidCells
            If Not Cell.Validation.Value Then
                Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                Let Fail = True
            Else
                Cell.Interior.Color = xlNone
            End If
        Next
        
        If Fail Then
            MsgBox "Please rectify the red background data"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This works well when copy paste data. Except when input wrong data, it will pop up many MsgBox（triggered by Validation and Macro）.

Is there a way to distinguish what action traggers the change event, So I can choose if needed to show MsgBox in the macro.

Comment: That code is triggered when you change any cell in the range A2:D2000.

Comment: Yeah, when paste wrong data it'll show one MsgBox. But Input wrong data it'll show many MsgBox. I have no idea how to show only one MsgBox when input wrong data.

Comment: Presumably when inputting you are doing one cell at a time?

Comment: Yeah,  input only on one cell each time.

Comment: That's why you get an error each time. Not sure you can get round that. You could instead perhaps store the error cells and only show a message box when they reach a count of eg 10.

Comment: In such a case, the `Change` event should not be triggered. It is triggered only if the cell value has been changed. If it is not in the list, you receive only the validation warning, not letting you to change the validated cell value... If not something confidential, can you share the workbook in discussion? Even with dummy data... Then, `KeyCells.Width` will raise an error, if not a typo...

Comment: Yeah it's a typo.

Comment: @FaneDuru how can I share the demo file to you.

Comment: If you want sharing it (only) to me, there is a personal mail account in my profile. Otherwise, you can use a transfer site and let everybody seeing it. [Here](https://easyupload.io/) is a free one, an easy to be used... If you prefer sending it on my mail, please, tag me here and say that. Otherwise, my mail is set to not accept mails from people not being on my address book.

Comment: Is your validation a list type?

Comment: text length, when I input nothing, it will cause at least two msg box

Comment: Why not just run the code when target.count>1 ?

Comment: But, do you want it accepting blank values? If not, why did not tick 'Ignore Blank' check box? You can also add a line in the event code. Something like `If Target.value = "" then Exit Sub`.

Comment: @FaneDuru https://github.com/LF00/demo/blob/main/demo.xlsm  You can test on the A column and B column

Comment: Yeah,  filter out the empty string in the macro works.

Comment: Not sure I understood what you mean by "empty string in the macro works"... Do you mean that applied my above suggestion? Now, how would you like the sheet to behave in case of trying to change an empty cell with a string of only one digit? Now, a warning appears (probably, informing about the two digits minimum) and in case of `Cancel` the event colors the interior in red. Is it the problem that the `MsgBox` does appear twice?

Comment: Not sure if this will help but firstly, try not to use reserved words as your variable names (i.e. `Cell`. I tend to use `oCell`). Also, have you tried disabling events? (**Application.EnableEvents = False** and then **Application.EnableEvents = True** at the end)

Answer (score 1):

In order to make your code to color the cel interior in case of no validated value, try the next way, please:

```
Option Explicit
Private boolEv As Boolean

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2:D2000")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Not Target.Validation.Value Then
            If Not boolEv Then
                Target.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                MsgBox "rectify": boolEv = True
            Else
                boolEv = False
            End If
        Else
            Target.Interior.Color = xlNone
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

The `Boolean` variable is necessary because the event is triggered twice, in case of the initial cell is empty. Firstly for the accepted value (pressing `Cancel`) and secondly after coming back to the initial value (emptiness). In this way, the second (parasite) event is skipped...

Using `If Target.value = "" then Exit Sub` will not let the event to color the cell interior and send the message.